# mysql prepared statement no repeat variables in execute stmt using

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

Supposing some like this

```
SET @var1 = 'val1';
SET @var2 = 'val2';

SET @query = "
    INSERT INTO my_table
    VALUES
    (?,?),
    (?,?),
    -- ... imagine here a lot of values
    (?,?)
";

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt USING @var1,@var2,@var1,@var2,@var1,@var2;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Have there a way to write only one time the variables on `EXECUTE stmt USING` ?

Some like this:

```
EXECUTE stmt USING @var1,@var2;
```

In this case get error

> Incorrect arguments to execute statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL supports positional query parameters, not named query parameters.

You must have the same number of parameter placeholders in the SQL query as the number of parameter values you pass to `EXECUTE`.

This would be easier if you prepare and execute your query in some application language like Java, Ruby, or Python, instead of using `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`.